# Need to integrate function without losing dependence of a variable

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

Is there a way to integrate the following so that $f(t,z)$ does not lose its dependence on $t$? (Both $f(t,z)$ and $g(t')$ are integrable functions; $r$ is some constant.)

$f(t,z)=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}dk \int^t_0dt'g(t') \text{e}^{ik(z+rt')}$

I've tried integrating over $k$ first, then obtaining a $\delta$ function and finally integrating over $t'$. However, this gives $f(t,z)$ as a function of $z$ only:

$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}dk \int^t_0dt'g(t') \text{e}^{ik(z+rt')}=2\pi\int^t_0dt'g(t') \dfrac{\delta(z/r+t')}{r}=\dfrac{2\pi g(-z/r)}{r}$$

Edit: $f(t)$ amended to $f(t,z)$; $r$ defined to be just some constant.

Comment: You must have made some mistake. The way you wrote it, that integral defines a function of $(t, r, z)$ (provided it converges, of course).

Comment: Can you show your steps?  The way you are describing is correct, but $t$ shouldn't disappear in the integration over $t'$.